# create a json object from html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a json object using contents from a wiki page ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_academic_disciplines)), in the section `Contents` I want to extract all the contents and create an object like this :

```
{
Arts : {
"Performing Arts" : [{"Music" : [
        {"title" : "Accompanying"},
        {"title" : "Chamber music"},
        {"title" : "Church music"},
        {"Conducting" : [
          {"title" : "Choral conducting"},
          {"title" : "Orchestral conducting"},
          {"title" : "Wind ensemble conducting"}
        ]},{....}],
"Visual arts" : [all its sub-child]
}
```

So what I tried is that I copied the source html code which looks like this (for each section (`Arts`, `Humanities` ...), here I only gave an example of the first section `Arts`) :

`h2` which contains the first section `Arts` and then its followed by `h3` elements each one of these elements contains the title of the sub child (`Performing arts`, `Visual arts`, ...) and each of these `h3` elements are followed by a `div` elements wich contains a single `ul` element, each of these `ul` elements are followed by a list of `li` elements, each of these `li` elements contains the title of the sub sub child (for example `Performing arts` contains `Music`, `Dance`, ...), and if this sub sub child contains other childs it will be followed by a single `ul` element which contains a list of `li` elements, these elements contains the title of the sub sub sub child (for example `Conducting` contains `Choral conducting`, `Orchestral conducting`, ...) and so on ...

So I tried something like this :

```
var json = [];

$("body").find('h2').each(function(){
    var h2 = $(this).find('span').first().text();
    var childs = $(this).nextAll('h3');
    childs.each(function(){
      var h3 = $(this).find('span').first().text();
      subChilds = $(this).next('div');
      subChilds.each(function(){
        subSubChilds = $(this).next('ul');
        console.log(subSubChilds);
      })
        })
});
```

But then I got stack, I don't know how I continue.

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/9444/ (In this fiddle I only copied the source code of the first two sections `Arts` and `Humanities`)

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I don't know on which purpose you are trying to scrape information from an HTML Wikipedia page, but there is an API to get wikipedia articles in machine readable formats: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse it with a recursive function, like this:

```
function parseRecursive(ul, result) {
  result = result || [];
  var childs = ul.children('li');
  childs.each(function() {
    var child = $(this);
    var title = child.find('a').eq(0).text();
    var r = {};
    var subLevel = child.find('ul');

    if (subLevel.length > 0) {
      r[title] = parseRecursive(subLevel, []);
    } else {
      r.title = title;
    }

    result.push(r);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/9448/).

Answer (score 0):

if you see the document object in jquery

[image]

you can traverse through every element of page with this.

to convert the html page to json I suggest you this way will be easier

```
var jsonObjectOfDoc=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(document));
```

now you can play with json.

I haven't tested the code, just suggesting you a path to go,hope this will help. looking for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not the exact outcome that you want. Hopefully you can figure out how to change it to get what you need. Just wanted to help you get past the parts you were stuck on.

```
var json = [];

//Selecting all of the h2s seems fine
$("body").find('h2').each(function() {
  //persobally I would use the class, but I did not change your org code
  var h2 = $(this).find('span').first().text();

  //create a new object using the text you found
  json[h2] = {};

  //Now you need to select only the child h3s
  // To do this, you need to select all of the siblings until you reach the next h2
  // than you need to figure the h3 elements out of the set
  var childs = $(this).nextUntil("h2").filter("h3");

  //loop over the h3 elements
  childs.each(function() {

    //grab the headlines text
    var h3 = $(this).find(".mw-headline").text();

    //find the sibling div, and select all of the first anchors
    // loop over the anchors and get the text and use map and get to output an array
    var items = $(this)
      .next("div").find("ul li a:first-child")
      .map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
      }).get();

    //add the array of items to the key in our object
    json[h2][h3] = items;

  });

});

//display the result of the looping
console.log(json);
```

Now what you need to do is instead of returning the text, you need to return the object so you get your output.